# javac responds with "not a file" but the file exists

Tags: java, powershell

When I compile one Java file with javac, it responds with the error `not a file` (instead of `file not found`):

[image]

So I tried to compile it in the WSL environment and it compiles the same file fine. Then, I realized that it may be because I put the file under OneDrive, so I moved it out of OneDrive and tried it again, and then `javac` worked:

[image]

After that, I created an empty java file under Onedrive and tried again, which also shows the `not a file` error:

[image]

Then, I started to realize that when I "dir" in PowerShell, the mode of files under OneDrive include one "l" symbol, which represents "reparse point". Although I do not really understand what it means, I am curious whether it is because of the `l` that I can not compile the java file. Or if is there any other potential problems.

Comment: @EdinMujakic `.` is the current directory, so `.\<file>` is a file in the current directory. It's just how powershell auto-completes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the first image you posted you can see this:

```
> dir
Mode     Name
-a---l   helloworld.java
```

So, what that `l` at the end of the mode means is that `helloworld.java` is not a file, it's a symlink. And that's what `javac` is telling you.

The example you posted in the second image works because that one is actually a file (see the Mode column says `-a----`).

The problem is caused by OneDrive, it seems what we see as files are not actually the files but links that point to those files. To avoid the problem, don't place your java files inside the OneDrive folder.

Comment: thanks for your helpful answer. However, I am currently wondering why it is fine to compile in WSL...since I compiled the same file under OneDrive

Comment: It is because `javac` in WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) follows the symlink to the real file, just as `javac` in Linux does.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: I've had the same issue but only on some of my computers. It appears if you disable the Files On-Demand setting in OneDrive it will store the files locally instead of as links. This lets you use javac directly but it also means all of you OneDrive files will be stored locally which can use a lot of space.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it works for newly created files, thank you!