# "javac: not a file: ..." compilation error?

Tags: java

I'm using jGrasp for a school project, and I only recently started getting this error. I already tried troubleshooting on here and on other forums, but with little success.  I already created a JAVA_HOME variable and set my path variable to %JAVA_HOME%\bin, but this did not allow me to compile my code.  My TA told me to reinstall the jdk, which I did and reset my path to the newest jdk version.  This did not help either.

[Here is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K85g0.png)

Comment: I don't think the JDK is the problem. I think it has to do with the file you're trying to compile. For example, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48361702/javac-responds-with-not-a-file-but-the-file-exists

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect the cause are **the blanks** in the folders names. You'd better rename the parent folders to strip all the blanks off.