# What does "javac: not a file: HelloWorld.java" mean?

Tags: java, installation

I am trying to run a simple Java "Hello World!" program and I am having issues.
I think I successfully installed java and the new jdk 10.0.1.
On CMD, I can type javac and it'll work. However, my simple HelloWorld.java won't make a HelloWorld.class for some reason.

I think the problem has to do with my environmental variables and/or path... 
I typed path on command prompt and it looks like this:

```
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.1;C:\Users\melan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
```

My program does not compile and this is what it looks like:

```
C:\Users\melan\OneDrive\Documents\javafolder>javac HelloWorld.java

javac: not a file: HelloWorld.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options
```

*Edit: I believe the HelloWorld.java is in the right place

Directory of C:\Users\melan\OneDrive\Documents\javafolder

```
05/12/2018  07:30 PM    <DIR>          .
05/12/2018  07:30 PM    <DIR>          ..
05/12/2018  06:15 PM               277 HelloWorld.java
               1 File(s)            277 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  937,982,566,400 bytes free
```

Comment: javac runs and give you response, so the environment is OK. The message javac gave you `javac: not a file: HelloWorld.java`, so please check the `HelloWorld.java` file or folder or something else.

Comment: The message is telling you that `HelloWorld.java` does not exist within `C:\Users\melan\OneDrive\Documents\javafolder`.

Comment: Directory of C:\Users\melan\OneDrive\Documents\javafolder

05/12/2018  07:30 PM    <DIR>          .
05/12/2018  07:30 PM    <DIR>          ..
05/12/2018  06:15 PM               277 HelloWorld.java
               1 File(s)            277 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  937,982,566,400 bytes free

Comment: @JimGarrison no this message is not about a not exist file, the relevent message would be "file not found".

Comment: Try run `dir` under powershell like this PO does https://stackoverflow.com/q/48361702  . Maybe you are facing the same symbol link issue?

Comment: @TKJohn OK, then it means there's a _directory_ called HelloWorld.java

Comment: @JimGarrison since this PO is using OneDrive, too, it is quite possible the `HelloWorld.java` is a symbolic link file, which javac cannot handle.

Comment: That was going to be my next guess.  The object `HelloWorld.java` is not being recognized as a regular file by `javac`.  I've had the same issues with Google Drive mirroring in a few cases (not Java-related).

Comment: @Mel  Try copying the file to a local directory not being managed by OneDrive and try compiling there.

Comment: Alright I'll try to get off OneDrive ....

Comment: @JimGarrison,  IT  WORKED! Finally Ran my first JAVA code, THANKS! The problem was with OneDrive. ty everyone

Comment: @Mel This question has value for the future, so you should self-answer it, explaining what you did and what the problem was.  Then after the required waiting period “accept” your own answer.  That way others with the same issue in the future will be able to find the answer easily.